# C++ constexpr thread_local id

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, thread-local

Is there any way to get a different value in a constexpr thread_local variable for every thread?

```
constexpr thread_local someType someVar = ......;
```

It seems like constexpr thread_local is supported but the thread_local indicator doesnt seem to do anything in this case.

Comment: You seem to have some conflicting requirements. `constexpr` is for compile-time constants, while threads are a pure run-time concept. What is it you're trying to do? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Please take some time to read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and think about how it relates to this question.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I want to check whether something will be called from the right thread at compile-time

Comment: You might be looking for [`std::this_thread::get_id()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id).

Comment: Well you can't do that. Calls happen at run-time, you can't make run-time checks at compile-time, it's simply not possible. Perhaps it's time to think (or rather *re*think) about your requirements or your design?

Comment: Seems like there is no way to set a thread_local type even thought constexpr is supported all threads will always have the same value in that constexpr thread_local?

Comment: Always having the same value means "const".  Known at compile time is "constexpr". If you want a different value for different threads, just do that without trying to call it constexpr (which it is not).

Comment: If I make two threads in my main function then it is known at compile time that these two threads will exist and have thread locals right? Why wouldn't I be able to give them constexpr ID's. Seems like the only way to check which thread I am coming from at compile time is to pass on type tokens.

Comment: If they were constexpr (which they are not) then it would be possible for the compiler to remove the if from this code "if (UI_THREAD_ID == someVar) {...}" because it knows at compile time what the values are. If you don't know the value before the code even runs, then it's not constexpr.

Comment: While mixing `constexpr` and `thread_local` seems silly at first the OP does have a point. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6858fcf260bb09c6). If I understand right the OP is looking for a way to not have to type `template <int id>` in front of every function and `<id>` in every function call which is a reasonable thing to want.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I mean, if there would be something like a constexpr thread constructor or something like that we wouldn't have to pass tockets or do runtime checks but we could check the thread safety of statically known threads at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about your question, you yourself can see why this is not possible.

**What is `constexpr`?**

According to the informal standard site [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr):

> The constexpr specifier declares that it is possible to evaluate the value of the function or variable at **compile time**.

The compiler has to resolve the value at compile time and this value should not change throughout the execution of the program.

**Thread-local storage**

A thread, on the contrary, is a run-time concept. C++11 introduced the thread concept into the language, and thus you could say that a compiler can be "aware" of the thread concept.
But, the compiler can't always predict if a thread is going to be executed (Maybe you run the thread only upon specific configuration), or how many instances are going to be spawn, etc.

**Possible implementation**

Instead of trying to enforce access to a specific module/method to a single thread using hacks and tricks, why not use a very primitive feature of the language?

You could just as well implement this using simple encapsulation. Just make sure that the only object that "sees" this method you are trying to protect is the thread object itself, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class SpecialWorker
{
public:
    void start()
    {
        m_thread = std::move(std::thread(&SpecialWorker::run, this));
    }

    void join()
    {
        m_thread.join();
    }

protected:
    virtual void run() { protectedTask(); }

private:
    void protectedTask()
    {
        cout << "PROTECT ME!" << endl;
    }

    std::thread m_thread;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    SpecialWorker a;
    a.start();
    a.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Please note that this example is lacking in error handling and is not production grade code! Make sure to refine it if you intend to use it.